# set the color coding for a codeblock

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Most of the time all codeblocks you post are colored in the right way automatically. But not always.

Is there a way to tell the interpreter here that a block is javaScript for example annd then it is colored the right way?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with the new [Syntax Highlighting Hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75019/245827).

For Javascipt, you'd insert this above the code block, surrounded by empty lines:

```javascript
­
<!-- language: lang-javascript -->

//Javascript goes here
```

Though by default, any code on a question tagged with the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag would be given Javascript syntax highlighting by default, unless otherwise specified using this:

```
­
<!-- language: none -->

Something you don't want syntax highlighted goes here
```

Comment: I think you need a blank line before and after it, IIRC

Comment: @Plutonix I just tested and you're right, I've edited my post.

Comment: They are not "new".