# Why on earth does "Hello" have syntax highlighting?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

As can be seen is this image here, `hello` appears to have syntax highlighting when the language is specified like this. `<!-- language: lang-python -->`. This can also be seen is this image here.

> [image]

This is pretty odd, and I'm wondering if this is an unintentional bug, or some tricky Easter egg. Just to see, I'm going to test it here too to see if it works on other sites than just meta.SE.

```python
Hello, this is a test.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The syntax highlighter has no knowledge of the Python interactive interpreter format, and interprets the `Hello, this is a test.` line as *code*.

It simply highlighted `Hello` as a type (in Python, anything with a capital initial is assumed to be a class or type). Up until `this` the line *could* have been an expression, after all. `is` is recognised as a language keyword and highlighted as such.

```py
>>> print (
    "Firstword, is highlighted as an identifier. It does not matter if it is\n"
    "Hello or something else. \"Quotes\" look like 'strings'.")
Firstword, is highlighted as an identifier. It does not matter if it is
Hello or something else. "Quotes" look like 'strings'.
```

This is hardly the fault of the language parser however; the interpreter is echoing 'random' text in between valid code and the parser has no way of knowing what is supposed to be code and what is text.

Note that bugs in how a specific language is marked up, should be reported to the [Google prettify project](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), not to Stack Exchange.

Comment: So don't put both code and output into the same code block. Use [lang-none](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258565/set-the-color-coding-for-a-codeblock/258567#258567) to suppress code highlighting.

Comment: @Jongware: I simply put up with the highlighting idiosyncrasies. In the end it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Do I guess correctly based on your last comment that you are a fan of Linkin Park?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Heh, not really. I have *Hybrid Theory* but I wasn't consciously referring to the track, nor am I specifically a fan. :-)

Comment: It's highlighted because it's capitalised, which the parser will interpret as a class name. If it was all lower case (and not a keyword) it'd escape... I agree though, it doesn't matter much and could be a possible future improvement to Prettify.

Comment: @Ben: Right; it uses `typ`, the highlight for types and classes, indeed.